# How to dynamicly append a new row to my table of html?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The following is some codes in my project(in the sys_Params.aspx file):

```
 <tr class="TR_BG_list" id="printsizescroll" style="display:none">
<td align="right" class="list_link" style="width: 214px">
    Resize the picture：
</td>
<td align="left" class="list_link">

            Description:
<asp:TextBox ID="PrintSizeDec" runat="server" CssClass="form"  style="width: 106px"/>
            width|height:
<asp:TextBox ID="PrintSmallSize" runat="server" CssClass="form"  style="width: 50px"/>
    &nbsp;
     <label>
<input type="button" name="PintSizeAddClick" value="Add" class="form" id="ButtonAdd" style="width: 44px" onclick="createInputTexts(this)" />
</label>
<span class="helpstyle" style="cursor: help;" title="click for some help" onclick="Help('H_WaterParam_0008',this)">Help</span>
</td>
```

The question is I want to add a new row (the same as the previous  row ) dynamicly when I press the [add] button. 
I try to do that in this way,but it seems doesn't work fine, it is presented in the wrong format:

```
function createInputTexts() {             
    var trOrigin = $("#printsizescroll");
    var trClone = trOrigin.clone(true);
    var target = $("#printTbl tr:last-child").prev();
    trClone.appendTo(target);
}
```

Comment: It might clone the display meaning the clone is hidden as well. Try `trClone.show();`.

Comment: But it can't display in the right format. does it has something to do with the use of server controll TEXTBOX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createInputTexts() {             
    var trOrigin = $("#printsizescroll");
    var trClone = trOrigin.clone(true);
    var target = $("#printTbl tr").append(trClone);
}
```

OR

```
function createInputTexts() {             
    var trOrigin = $("#printsizescroll");
    var trClone = trOrigin.clone(true);
    var target = $("#printTbl tr:last-child").prev();
    trClone.css('display', '');
    // Here you can also set new ID.
    target.after(trClone);
}
```

This should work fine. You are appending the row in wrong way.

Comment: I am sorry it still works in the wrong way, and look more serious when I try your way; For the first answer, when I click the add button, it will add more then ten rows once time. And When I try the second answer you provided, the previous row disappeared and of course ,nothing was appended to the table.

Comment: You showed the cloned row using (display, '').
sometime whey you use display block this will break the table. use empty quotes instead. let the browser decide to display it.

Comment: I found that when I copy the whole <tr/> and paste it in the right position , the id of <tr> and <asp:textbox> is automaticly altered by the visual studio and it works fine!  But how can I add it dynamiclly?How about setting a new id the the new elements?

Comment: Thx a millious, it looks fine now by the help of your second answer. But how to add the id is also a big question, cause I need to save all the datas to the sqlserver, so I think I have to set the ids . do you have any suggestions?

Comment: how about this? You can use some random strings as IDs. Because Ids never posted back on sever.

Comment: how to make some random strings? And when I use the random string,how can I retrieve the datas which I want to persist in the database?

Comment: I need to get the datas of the textBox in the sys_Param.aspx.cs ,which is the code behind

Comment: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/random.html
there you can find the random string generation. beside this you get the form elements in code behind by name. So there would not be any trouble.

Comment: By the random-string IDs ,how can I get the content in the textBox in the code behind(in the .aspx.cs file)?